# Email_hashes decode

Tags: web-applications

I have javascript provided by Interactive Live SDK which returns all the contact details from the hotmail.But the main problem is that it returns contact Information in this format.And i want the email address in plain text.

Eg:-"id":"contact.8bd167c6000000000000000000000000", "first_name":"mukunda", "last_name":"marthy", "name":"mukunda marthy", "gender":null, "is_friend":false, "is_favorite":false, "user_id":null,
"email_hashes":["243c01e30cfdbc8c46b8dddb68a685bb8f86016096fd3398919ed6845fde6b7b"], "updated_time":"2013-06-20T05:59:00+0000"

how can i convert this above email_hashes into a plain text email address.
or 
if we can not convert into plain text then please let me know,how can i use the email_hashes to send emails from my web application.